# I try to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, primes

I tried to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes to check if numbers are prime numbers in Python. If i run the Programm, it shows me: "Process finished with exit code 0". What's the mistake?

```
def primzahl(n):

    primzahlen = []
    numbers = list(range(2,n))
    c = 2
    while c*c < n:
        for k in range(c,n,c):
            if k in numbers:
                numbers.remove(k)
        primzahlen.append(c)
        c = numbers[0]

    return primzahlen + numbers
    print(primzahl(100))
```

Comment: i edited your code... was the `print` statement where it is now (it should not!)...

Comment: Hi @hiroprotagonist, your edit will count as an attempt to reply and most likely will be rejected IMO!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh i think you misunderstand: i did not try to fix the code; just marked all of it (including thist last `print` statement) and shifted it 4 spaces to the right such that it appears as code.

Comment: Aah, when you said ` was the print statement where it is now (it should not!)`, then I thought you modified the print statement to unindent it! My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Just unindent your `print` statement to take it out of the function.

```
def primzahl(n):

    primzahlen = []
    numbers = list(range(2,n))
    c = 2
    while c*c < n:
        for k in range(c,n,c):
            if k in numbers:
                numbers.remove(k)
        primzahlen.append(c)
        c = numbers[0]

    return primzahlen + numbers

#Unindent this statement
print(primzahl(100))
```

The output is then

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help! It would be great if you could mark by answer as accepted @bijankhr :)